# jQuery: Using toggle buttons to move items between multiple lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, list, toggle, togglebutton

I have three lists, each item has a tool bar of buttons . The lists are staged, live and pinned.  I'm trying to use the toggle buttons to move the items between the lists. As you can see from the jsfiddle  example below, I have the buttons moving the items, but I've encountered two problems I was hoping to get some help with.  I'm a visual learner, I've looked all over Stackoverflow and Google for an example with no luck.

*Notes* - The edit and trash buttons don't move items.  I will be executing an ajax call within each toggle action to commit each change, I noted this in my js file.

Working Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/RuRdZ/3/

**The Problems**:

1 - When you click on a button, for example 'Make Live'  in the staged list, the item properly moves to the live list but the buttons on this item seem to become disabled - after the move I cannot delete the item or make it staged again.  This will be a problem because my goal is to not have the page refresh.

2 - Again when moving an item from list to list, I was trying to figure out how to make the proper buttons disappear/appear .  For example if I make a staged item live, when the item moves, I'd like to hide the 'make live' button and show the 'stage' button.  I've tried several things but I don't think I'm using the right selector.  In each heading I listed the proper buttons that should appear in each list.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not use clone, appending existed element to another one removes it from original container element - it solves the problem with buttons events

do all actions in one handler - then you'll get the control over buttons to show or hide them accordingly

e.g.

```
function doAction($element, buttonsToHide, $containerAppendTo) {
  $containerAppendTo.append(element);
  //loop over all buttons inside clicked li
  $('.fg-buttonset', $element).each(function(){
    $currBtn = $(this);

    $currBtn.toggle(!$currBtn.hasClass(buttonsToHide)); //show|hide if needed
  });
}

  $(".doStage").click(function() {
    var $el = $(this).closest('li');
    doAction($el, 'stagedButton', $('#test-list3'));
  });
```

Comment: Irishka - thank you, your solution is so much simpler than mine and makes more sense.
Two questions, how do I pass multiple 'buttonsToHide' classes at one time to doAction? I tried ('liveButton', 'stagedButton' ) and other variants but I can only get one class to ever toggle.  Finally, is it correct syntax that I should be initially hiding some of the buttons? See my updated code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/MZyRS/

Thank you again!

Comment: I did a lot of trial and error over the weekend but I believe I have new version of the code that I believe does the job. The only issue is that JSLint says there is an implied global error - I'm not sure if I should take this serious or not? Nonetheless, does this code look stable? http://jsfiddle.net/TaepQ/ Any advice is welcomed, thanks again!

Comment: the code looks ok, but you can give your buttons an additioanl global class, like 'actButton', and then hide all of them at once $('.actButton').hide(); the same for buttons that belongs to one group . e.g. stageButton, pinButton, then you do not need to call them separatelly

Comment: and this: for (var i = 0, btnClass; btnClass= buttonsToToggle[i]; i++) {
                $currBtn = $(this);
                if ($currBtn.hasClass(btnClass)) {
                    $currBtn.toggle();
                }
            } - can be written as $currBtn.toggle(!$currBtn.is(buttonsToToggle)); where buttonsToToggle = '.class1, .class2';